# PyGame - Take a screenshot of a certain part of the display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How can I take a screenshot of a certain part of the pygame screen?

For example, this is my screen

[image: screen]

and I want to take a screenshot of the area between the top-left dot, and the bottom-right dot (the coordinate are (20, 100), (480, 480), and the whole display is 500x50).

This is my best result so far (but it's still not good):

```
def screenshot(obj, file_name, position, size):
    img = pygame.Surface(size_f)
    img.blit(obj, (0, 0), (position, size))
    pygame.image.save(img, file_name)
...
...
...
screenshot(game, "test1.png", (0, 100), (500, 400))
```

[image: screen]

I added the black border to show the image border, because the image is white.

---------- EDIT ----------

with this function call

```
screenshot(game, "test1.png", (20, 100), (480, 400))
```

i'm getting a better result - now both the top and the left sides are ok, (because the top-left is the point where the x and y starts) but still - both the right and the bottom sides aren't good

i.imgur.com/prH2WOB.png

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take screenshot of certain part of screen in Pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267395/how-to-take-screenshot-of-certain-part-of-screen-in-pygame)

Comment: no, i've already tried this.. there is always padding around, because the selection is in the center (and not full-width) so I can't specify the exact coordinate with this method (from the link)

Comment: But your code does work and does exactly what would be expected. It takes a screenshot from the coordinates you've given. What else are you trying to do?

Comment: The top side is good, but the bottom, right and left sides, aren't good - there is like padding, and i'm trying to get result without any padding - like the top side. If there is no way to do that with PyGame, so maybe there is an easy way to do this in 2 steps - 1) the screenshot (what I already have) and 2) to cut the image with other python library. (I prefer a method with one step, but if PyGame doesn't provide this, so two-steps method is also fine)

Comment: @noam I explained in further detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your function has an error (size_f is not defined) but otherwise it's working. The function

```
def screenshot(obj, file_name, position, size):
    img = pygame.Surface(size)
    img.blit(obj, (0, 0), (position, size))
    pygame.image.save(img, file_name)
```

takes the the topleft position and the size of the rectangle. You said yourself that the topleft red dot is at `(20, 100)`, so the *position* argument should be at `(20, 100)` (that's why your second attempt fixes the padding to the left and top).

The bottomright point is determined by the size of the rectangle. We're trying to get from `(20, 100)`to `(480, 480)`, so some quick math will give us the size:

```
width = 480 - 20 = 460
height = 480 - 100 = 380
```

Your function should give the right result if you do like this:

```
screenshot(game, "test1.png", (20, 100), (460, 380))
```

You could do this if you want to change the function to take two positions instead:

```
def screenshot(obj, file_name, topleft, bottomright):
    size = bottomright[0] - topleft[0], bottomright[1] - topleft[1]
    img = pygame.Surface(size)
    img.blit(obj, (0, 0), (topleft, size))
    pygame.image.save(img, file_name)
```

Here's an example demonstrating both functions:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def screenshot(obj, file_name, position, size):
    img = pygame.Surface(size)
    img.blit(obj, (0, 0), (position, size))
    pygame.image.save(img, file_name)


def screenshot2(obj, file_name, topleft, bottomright):
    size = bottomright[0] - topleft[0], bottomright[1] - topleft[1]
    img = pygame.Surface(size)
    img.blit(obj, (0, 0), (topleft, size))
    pygame.image.save(img, file_name)

a = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
a.fill((255, 0, 0))


while 1:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                screenshot(screen, "test1.png", (20, 100), (460, 380))
                screenshot2(screen, "test2.png", (20, 100), (480, 480))
                print("PRINTED")
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    screen.blit(a, (20, 100))
    screen.blit(a, (480, 480))
    pygame.display.update()
```