Why is my tkinter/customtkinter window the wrong size?
I have a problem with the size of my window. I set the .geometry of my root to "700x600". When I start the program, my window opens with the size "875x750" (I initialized an event, that gives me the size of my window every time).
Also when I set .minsize to width: 320 and height: 400, the window just scales down to 400x500. When I use another monitor, I get a minimum scale of 480x600.
Can somebody tell me, how I can fix this?
I tried to put the settings down by difference, but every monitor had different differences.

It may be your system scaling factor is set to 125%.

this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55127025/6074182

@acw1668, tyvm. Ur right. Thats the problem.

@acw1668, that's clever!

Do you have any widgets present in your root ? I know that for frames it automatically adjusts to the widget inside so if you have a text the geometry you hardcoded will not be relevent anymore. I'm not sure if that's also tkinter's behaviour with root.

yes, but it doesnt get relevance, because my frames are relative placed to root. but i've got the solution. The problem was by the system scaling factor.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
